# file treansfer from windows OS to unix in Java

Tags: java, ftp, cross-platform

I create a pdf file in runtime (in Windows OS).  I need to copy it to another location, it might be on UNIX or windows.  Is there a java class I can do it with? and how?  Thanks.

Comment: Am not sure what you wanna to achive but you can use STAF to copy files from unix to windows OS or vice -versa...

Comment: And there must be some class in java to achieve FTP since in ruby we have some built in classes to achieve FTP ...

Comment: Before thinking how to do this in Java, think about how you would do it manually? Do the other locations already have a service running that allows file transfer? FTP? SSH? Windows Shares? SAFT? ... Decide, and then look for a library that supports it.

Answer (score 5):

```
URL url = 
    new URL("ftp://username:password@ftp.localhost/file.pdf;type=i");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
BufferedInputStream in = 
    new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
FileOutputStream out = 
    new FileOutputStream("C:\\file.pdf");

int i = 0;
byte[] bytesIn = new byte[1024];
while ((i = in.read(bytesIn)) >= 0) {
    out.write(bytesIn, 0, i);
}
out.close();
in.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers, Mohamed's answer did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the file in the directory space of an FTP server (on your Windows machine), you can use `URLConnection` in a Java app on a remove client to fetch it.  See @Mohamed Saligh's answer for example code.  (The key is to use an "ftp:" URL, and to force the transfer type to be binary.)

Other resources that may help include the [Apache Commons FTP Client library](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-release/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/package-frame.html), and the [Apache Mina FTP server](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/).  The FTP client library would allow you to "push" the file to an FTP server on Windows / UNIX ... as well as "pull" it as `URLConnection` does.

There are various other Java FTP clients, servers and libraries "floating around the interwebs" ... according to a certain well-known search engine :-).